# Tracking motion of a convex hull

Tags: geometry, tracking, motion, convex-hull

I have two convex hulls and I was just wondering if anyone knows of any good algorithms or resources/ has any ideas on how to compare the position of one convex hull to another?

Distance, orientation and similarity would be a great start.

Comment: Define "comparing the position". Distance? Orientation?

Comment: What do you want? The intersections? The minimum distance? The distance between the mass centers? ... etc etc ... ?

Comment: anyone have a response regarding a change in the x-coordinate?